# How to store value from HTML text box by using Javascript local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

This is the method which I tried. I've added a feedback just to test out if the JavaScript variable siteName contains the value from the HTML textbox value but it reflected "[object HTMLInputElement]" instead. Any idea why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Storing HTML value into Javascript local storage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="2ndid">Hello</h1>

       <input type="text" id="firstid">
       <button onclick="myFunction()">LocalStorage</button>
       <button onclick="myFunction2()">Feedback</button>  

       <script type="text/javascript">
           var siteName = document.getElementById('firstid');
           function myFunction() {
               localStorage.setItem('store1', siteName);
           }
           function myFunction2() {
               document.getElementById("2ndid").innerHTML = siteName;
           }
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your `.setItem('strore1', siteName);` should be `siteName.value`

Comment: do you want to store the element instead of its data..?

Comment: instead of `var siteName = document.getElementById('firstid');` use `var siteName = document.getElementById('firstid').value;`

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko, omg it worked! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `value` property to get the actual text from the input. Otherwise it will return the reference of the input text field. The reference is type of `HTMLInputElement` which has a `value` property holding actual data entered in the text field.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Storing HTML value into Javascript local storage</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1 id="2ndid">Hello</h1>

   <input type="text" id="firstid">
   <button onclick="myFunction()">LocalStorage</button>
   <button onclick="myFunction2()">Feedback</button>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    var siteName;
    function myFunction() {
         siteName = document.getElementById('firstid').value;
         localStorage.setItem('store1', siteName);
    }
    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("2ndid").innerHTML = siteName;
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) of the input element to retrieve from value form it, or else you will be getting an object.

```
document.getElementById("2ndid").innerHTML = siteName.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple fix, you just have to add the value property at the end of the second fucntion.

```
function myFunction2() {
      document.getElementById("2ndid").innerHTML = siteName.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialising your variable.

here a working code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Storing HTML value into Javascript local storage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="2ndid">Hello</h1>

       <input type="text" id="firstid">
       <button onclick="myFunction()">LocalStorage</button>
       <button onclick="myFunction2()">Feedback</button>  

       <script type="text/javascript">
           var siteName;
           function myFunction() {
           siteName= document.getElementById('firstid').value;
               localStorage.setItem('store1', siteName);
           }
           function myFunction2() {
               document.getElementById("2ndid").innerHTML = siteName;
           }
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```